# Stop new PHP page poping up after a form button action

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my problem.

I have a from which uses a php file to do a request, which is add an entry to the db.

However after the request is actioned, because the form directs to a php file, a new window pops up with the echo of that php file.

Code of FORM

```
<form action='addsongnumber.php' method='post' target='searchresults'>
<input type='text' name='songid' value='" . $strTrackNo ."'>
<input type='submit' name='submit2' value=''>
</form>
```

PHP fILE

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$songid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['songid']);

$sql="UPDATE Music SET SongPlays = (SongPlays + 1) WHERE SongID = '$songid'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

???

Thanks universal consciousness :-D

Answer (score 0):

Remove the target attribute to stop the new window opening.

Have the PHP script return a [204](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) response to stop a new page loading.

```
http_response_code(204);
```

Comment: Then you would still end up with a blank page

Comment: @SanderVisser — You would not end up with a blank page. That's the point of a 204 response.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless from the new window popping out due to target (people before already mentioned what to do to deal with it), you need to process the form at your PHP page and then redirect to a different page (with a DONE message or whatever). Process the form and then do:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit();
```

Dont send any text output (this includes all echoes, white spaces etc.) before the header.

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like this?

```
<form action='addsongnumber.php' method='post' target="_parent">
```

using `target="_parent"` opens your action within the same window you are in.

Here is some more information on using `target`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp